# $*$–homomorphisms of the center of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras with centers $Z_A$ and $Z_B$. Suppose $\rho：A\rightarrow B$ is a surjective $*$- homomorphism. It is easy to check $\rho(Z_A)\subset Z(B)$.

I wonder how to assure that $\rho(Z_A) \neq Z(B)$?

If $rho$ is not surjective, what is the relationship between $\rho(Z_A)$ and $Z_B$?

Comment: I don't quite understand the wording of your question. Are you seeking an explicit example of $A$ and $B$ with a surjective star-homomorphism $\rho:A\to B$ for which $\rho(Z_A)\neq Z_B$? Or are you asking for some kind of characterization? I think I can produce a specific (counter)example, but I don't think there will be any sensible characterization of when the inclusion is strict.

Comment: Whether there exists some characterization? In Jorgen Vesterstrom's peper " on the homomorphism image of the cebter of a $C^*$-algebra", the author mentions some characterization. But      in that theorem, we need to know the concrete center, if we can calculate the center of $A$, how to determine whether $\rho(Z_A)$ is equal to $Z_B$?